# How to get priority the color instead of the image background

Tags: html, css

Helow guys, i tried z-index and other positioning to put the background color with transparency on the front after the background image, however i failed. Can anyone suggest an idea to solve the issue. Thanks you so much.

```css
body, 
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEz3G.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jury Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 100% height on body and html. The issue was your body element taking 0 height. Hence the background-color was not visible.

No need for z-index since body is already a child of html.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEz3G.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.5);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Jury Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple background and no need to define height. Simply rely on [background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-css-backgrounds-3-20171017/#special-backgrounds):

```css
html,body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html {
    background-image: 
     linear-gradient(rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.5),rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.5)),
     url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEz3G.jpg);
    background-size: 100px 100px,cover;
    background-repeat: repeat,no-repeat;
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Try This:-

```
body, 
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html {
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEz3G.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.5);
}
```